# Capybara fill_in multiple input fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, rspec, capybara

Below is my form, you can see that there will be many rows of inputs fields all with the same classes:

```
<%= q.simple_fields_for :choices do |c|%>
  <div class="row-fluid choice-row">
    <%= c.text_field :sort_order, class: 'span1' %>
    <%= c.text_field :title, class: 'span9' %>
    <%= c.link_to_remove 'Remove', class: 'btn btn-danger span2 pull-right' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

For my tests I'm trying:

```
fill_in(:sort_order, with: '3')
fill_in(:title, with: 'Choice 3')
```

I've also tried:

```
fill_in('Sort Order', with: '3')
fill_in('Title', with: 'Choice 3')
```

And:

```
fill_in('Sort Order', :with => '3')
fill_in('Title', :with => 'Choice 3')
```

The error I get is:

```
Failure/Error: fill_in(:title, with: 'Choice 3')
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id,         name, or label 'title' found
```

Can someone please recommend how I can fill a specific input, like say the third row?

Comment: Use the id of the field instead of `Title`.

Comment: I haven't assigned an id. And even if I do, won't every input have the same id. How do I distinguish between say the 3rd row of inputs and the 5th?

Comment: IDs are uniques for each field. You can inspect your fields to see which ID rails assign to it

Comment: it assigns it garbage id's like question_choice_attribute_45678987654567

Comment: Add actual HTML from the page rather than erb.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find in your markup that fields output by a form-helper are namespaced within the object passed to `fields_for`, this indeed the *entire point* of using `fields_for`.

In this case, your form elements will have names like `choices[title]` and `choices[sort_order]`.

To find and `fill_in` the correct field when selecting by name yields many fields, you need to get more creative, because this is not a very typical setup:

- You can use `within` to select a unique parent element
- You can use CSS selectors to find the `nth` element
- You can find all elements and use `[2]` on the returned array to access the 3rd element